# I want to hide id from url using htaccess in PHP

Tags: php, .htaccess

I'm trying to hide URL id
**from**
http://localhost/download/view.php?s_id=T7bPo
**to**
http://localhost/download/view/T7bPo

```
ReWriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^view/([0-9]+) view.php?s_id=$1
```

I tried many lines of code like

```
RewriteRule ^view/([^/\.]+)?$ /view.php?s_id=$1  [L]
RewriteRule ^view/+?$ /view.php?s_id=$1  [NC,L]
```

But failed everytime

> Error
>   **Object Not Found**
>
> As you can see below
>   [image]

Comment: try this    RewriteRule ^(.*)\/$ $1.php [NC]

Comment: A much simpler alternative, would be to use a POST request instead of a GET one.

Comment: @Abdul Rehman have this worked for you??????

Comment: @zbee how would that be an alternative? You don’t just arbitrarily switch between request methods to achieve a certain “look”, that makes very little sense.

Comment: Is this .htaccess inside the `downloads` folder to begin with? You might need to disable `MultiViews`, that is often the culprit if you have a partial “overlap” between the fake path you want to create, and the actual existing file name.

Answer (score 1):

If your .htaccess file is in /download/ folder check this rule on top of your rules:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteRule ^view\/(.*)$ /view.php?s_id=$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

If your .htaccess file is in / website root folder check this rule on top of your rules:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteRule ^download\/view\/(.*)$ /download/view.php?s_id=$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
#remove php file extension-e.g. https://example.com/file.php will become https://example.com/file
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

from https://www.plothost.com/kb/how-to-remove-php-html-extensions-with-htaccess/